# Solving $0 = -7\csc(x)\cot(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = 7\csc(x)$$

How do I solve this derivative when I set it equal to zero?
$$0 = -7\csc(x)\cot(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

From $0 = -7 \csc x \cot x$, we know that at least one of the factors $\csc x$ and $\cot x$ is equal to $0$. We then solve $\csc x = 0$ and $\cot x = 0$ to find all possible solutions. $\csc x = 0$ has no solutions, but $\cot x = 0$ gives us $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
0 = -7\csc x\cot x = \frac{-7\cos x}{\sin^2 x}.
$$
A fraction is $0$ precisely when the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is not $0$.  So
$$
\cos x=0 \text{ and } \sin x\ne0.
$$
Since there is no number whose sine and cosine are both $0$, this just means $$\cos x = 0.$$  Can you solve that?